# MS Access 10 - syntax error with constraints

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, keyword

I want to write a SQL query in MS Access 2010 for creating a table such that an attribute 'day' should have a value within a constraint I give using 'check' keyword. The check constraint is giving an error on saving the query.

I wrote a SQL query in MS Access 2010 as follows-

```
CREATE TABLE timeslot
(
    time_slot_id varchar (4),
    day varchar (1) check (day in ('M', 'T', 'W','R', 'F', 'S', 'U')),
    start_time time,
    end_time time,

    primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_time)
);
```

But on saving the query, I get an error pop-up saying

> SYNTAX ERROR IN CREATE TABLE STATEMENT

and it points at the check keyword. When I delete the check constraint, it runs successfully and the table timeslot is created without the constraint applied on 'day' attribute. Am I syntactically wrong in using 'check'? How do I apply the constraint on 'day' attribute?

Comment: this may help ... https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_check.asp

Answer (score 2):

[Day is a reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#D) and that name caused another syntax error in my test.  If you can't use a different name, enclose it in square brackets as below.

Since your issue is about a check constraint, I ignored the other fields.  So this is what worked for me in Access 2010:

```vb
Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
strCreate = "CREATE TABLE timeslot ([day] varchar(1), " & _
    "CONSTRAINT allowed_days CHECK ([day] IN ('M','T','W','R','F','S','U')))"
cn.Execute strCreate
```

Note a check constraint is only useable in Access DDL for statements executed in ANSI 92 mode.  My example worked because `CurrentProject.Connection` executes statements in ANSI 92 mode.

Later, if you are not fully satisfied with a check constraint for your field, consider using the field's *Validation Rule* property instead.

```vb
strCreate = "CREATE TABLE timeslot ([day] varchar(1))"
cn.Execute strCreate
strRule = "In ('M','T','W','R','F','S','U')"
Set db = CurrentDb
db.TableDefs("timeslot").Fields("day").ValidationRule = strRule
```

Answer (score 0):

`CHECK` is invalid there, you can move into its own clause (after a comma):

```
CREATE TABLE timeslot
(
    time_slot_id varchar (4),
    day varchar (1),
    start_time time,
    end_time time,

    primary key (time_slot_id, day, start_time),
    check (day in ('M', 'T', 'W','R', 'F', 'S', 'U'))
);
```

Comment: if the check code is invalid at that position, why is it still in your ddl

Comment: @nbk thanks for pointing that out, I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: @ErikA removed the edit. Thanks for pointing that out.